# Unix : Split line with delimiter

Tags: unix, split, cut

I've a file like this

```
a   b   c,d
e   f   g
x   y   r,s,t
```

and I would like to split this into columns using "," as delimiter. The other columns should be copied.

Expected result :

```
a   b   c
a   b   d
e   f   g
x   y   r  
x   y   s
x   y   t
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the column delimiter? Tab?

Comment: yes its a tab .

Answer (score 0):

Using awk. Expects field separators to be space or tab:

```
$ awk '{
    split($3,a,",")                   # split the third field on commas, hash to a
    for(i in a) {                     # for all entries in a
        sub(/[^ \t]+$/,a[i],$0)       # replace last field with entries in a...
        print                         # ... preserving separators, space or tab 
    }
}' file
a   b   c
a   b   d
e   f   g
x   y   r
x   y   s
x   y   t
```

Due to the use of `sub()` it will produce false results if there is a `&` in the `$3`. Also, as mentioned in the comments, using `for(i in a)` may result in records outputing in seemingly random order. If that is a problem, use:

```
$ awk '{
    n=split($3,a,",")                 # store element count to n
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {               # iterate in order
        sub(/[^ \t]+$/,a[i],$0)
        print
    }
}' file
```

For tab separated files:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }                    # output field separator
{
    n=split($3,a,",")
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        $3=a[i]                       # & friendly version
        print
    }
}' file
```

Comment: Notice that `for(i in a)` will only iterate arrays in order in GNU gawk (`gawk`). This may or may not matter in this case. Also, even if not asked in the Q, it would be great if you added a more general example, also able to handle `a,b,c   d e,f   g,h,i` brace-expansion wise ;-)